# Using RxJS with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a problem trying to use RxJS with TypeScript and Node.js. I am using NPM, and I have included `rxjs-es` version 5. I am also using Typings, and I have included both `es6-shim` and `rx.all`, like so:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "rx.all": "registry:dt/rx.all#2.2.28+20160316155526"
  }
}
```

Below is my `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

In a TypeScript file, I am trying to do the following:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

When I try to compile the script, I get the following error:

```
typings/main/ambient/rx.all/index.d.ts(10,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Rx'.
```

This happens even if I try to use RxJS within my script or not, so the problem is related to the TypeScript typings.

What do I need to install using typings and NPM in order to use RxJS? In particular, I am interested in using Observables. After Googling for hours, I cannot seem to figure out just what I need to make it work. I have tried [the following](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html), but without any luck. I have also tried many combinations of rx packages in NPM and typings, but haven't found anything that works. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an example of TypeScript + RxJs without Angular? I have a the same error: node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'  and I haven´t been able to fix it....
With just this import and no more core: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: How do you compile your TS source? `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'` should just work.

Answer (score 18):

RxJS 5 is written in typescript and its type definitions are included by default for published module, you may not need typings for `rx.all`. Actually those type definitions are written for previous versions of RxJS. Simply uninstall `rx.all` type definition and try to import without those.

Comment: but by default the types definations are not available. do you have any sample project without angularjs or other library

Answer (score 14):

The correct way of accomplishing this for [Angular](https://angular.io/) (not [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)) is by using @types from npm. The command is as follows:

```
npm install @types/rx --save-dev
```

For more information, see [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/rx).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you don't need to install typings separately, just including `rxjs/Rx` in your project should work (note the package name):

```
// installed with `$ npm i rxjs`
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx' // <- rxjs from NPM

Observable
    .of('Hello')
    .map( w => w + ' world!') // Annotated properly: (w: string) => string
    .subscribe(console.log.bind(console)) // 'Hello world!'
```

#### My `.tsconfig` (node)

Shouldn't be relevant, but feel free to use/compare.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "logs",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That typings file depends on Rx:

```
declare module "rx.all" {
    export = Rx;
}
```

Try installing "rx" as well as "rx.all":

```
typings install rx --save --ambient
```

But notice these typings assume you are importing "rx.all" or "rx" so your import will not give you typing info:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Can you import from "rx" instead of "rxjs"?

```
import { Observable } from 'rx';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install typings for RXJS by entering the following in your CLI.

```
typings install --global dt~es6-shim --save
```

This will add the following to your `typings.json`
`"es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504"`

Then add a reference path to the top of your typescript file

```
/// <reference path="typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />`
```

or to your tsconfig.json.

This will remove any typescript errors.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using TypeScript 2 you can try this.

```
typings install npm:rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts --save --global
```

Comment: isn't it @types now instead of typings...? confusing :)